# Issues with Forms Based Auth

Tags: sharepoint-server, forms-authentication

I recently configured FBA on a web application as a proof of concept.

I modified the 3 web.config files for sts/CA/webapp.  I created the site collection, and I can log in and add fba users.  Initially I could only login as the farm admin, but then I added authenticated users to the User Policy with full read, and then users could login.

However, after they login in, they get access denied when they try to access a list or library.  They seem to be able to browse to other areas of _layouts.  They also have full control to this site, so I'm not understanding why they can get to some areas but not others.